# Travel to Italy from the UK

Tags: uk, covid-19, italy

With the recent changes in UK rules and the amount of tests I have to take growing, I thought it would be best to get a second opinion on what I've planned:

- I am flying from Stansted to Treviso (Venice) on 12th December with Ryanair
- I am returning on the 15th December, also with Ryan air
- I am staying in Venice full time with my partner, we are both fully vaccinated

Regarding covid:

1. I have paid for Test to Return antigen test and a Day 2 PCR test with an approved gov.uk [partner](https://www.chronomics.com/covid-day-2-ttr) for both of us.
2. We have both filled out the [Italian registration form](https://app.euplf.eu/#/form).
3. We will fill out [Passenger Locator Form](https://www.gov.uk/provide-journey-contact-details-before-travel-uk) 48 hours before we enter the UK (and take our test to return at the same time).
4. Self isolate until the Day 2 PCR test comes back negative.
5. We also both have the NHS covid passport/QR through the NHS app.

I know I need to present to Ryanair a negative LFT/PCR test before departing the UK. But on all the Italian guidance nothing says it needs to be a "fit for travel" test, so can I present any lateral flow test (e.g. NHS one, since I take them multiple times a week anyway) or will Ryanair/Italy deny me entry for not having fit for travel test?

Is there anything else I need to know or do? I know the UK is on Italy's List D - which requires a negative test 48 hours before entry and proof of a full vaccine history.

Comment: NHS tests cannot be used for travel https://www.fitfortravel.nhs.uk/advice/disease-prevention-advice/covid-19-health-considerations-for-travel/coronavirus-covid-19-frequently-asked-questions This report is several months old but relates to Ryanair’s policy on the topic https://www.bbc.com/news/business-57243205

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I paid for the Fit for Flight tests and got the certificates for the way to Italy and my return to the UK. But Ryanair didn't once check these on the way out because they were in a rush and on the way back they just wanted proof of a negative test, which I showed them the fit for flight certificate.

**The border force for both Italy and the UK have all your records stored digitally through the PLF. This is probably where they can view the Fit for Flight certificates.**

Ultimately I think Fit for Flight tests are needed as it's checked automatically by border forces but it's still a waste of money as it's the same LFT that you take with the NHS (for me the exact same branded box). The only difference is you don't submit the result to the NHS, but rather their own system and they send you a PDF/certificate after.